# 1. Do I need to connect the neutral wire to a Raypak 5450 pool heater or just marrette it?

Tags: pool, heat-pump

This is for a Raypak 5450 Heat Pump pool heater.

Answer (score 3):

### Just cap it off

Your pool heater has no use for the neutral wire, so you can simply cap it off.